# Javascript - Change input Name if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, input

I have this :

```
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
```

What i need is, when i check the box, to change the name, from 
`name="nameX"`
to 
`name="nameY"`

For example, if i check the second box, will turn to:

```
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameY" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="nameX" value="myvalue1">
```

Comment: That is, frankly, a bizarre requirement. Inputs already have a checked property. Why do you need to hack the name so it duplicates information already stored on the object? (This is probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: Man, the name is checked, not <input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1" CHECKED>

Comment: Pure Javascript or you can use JQuery ?

Comment: @Google — Yes, you said that in the question. I understand what you want. I don't understand why you want it.

Comment: Is ok if javascript or jquery

Comment: @Google, Check me out in answer,

Comment: @Quentin To avoid PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. So when checkbox is not checked it wont pass the values to the next page,so it wont exceed the 1000

Comment: @Google — That won't make any difference. Checkboxes are are not checked will not be successful controls and won't be encoded in form data in the first place. (Assuming you are submitting a form normally and don't have some broken JS that is encoding the data instead, but failing to exclude unchecked check boxes … in which case you should fix that instead of hacking the names).

Comment: @Quentin your right, but all checkbox have values

Comment: @Google — That doesn't matter. If a checkbox is checked it will be successful. If a checkbox is not checked it will not be successful. Only successful checkboxes will be included in the submitted form data. If the checkbox has a value, it will submit that value. If it does not, it will submit `on`. It still has to be checked to submit anything.

Comment: @Quentin - I just test it out, your right :D Thanks for helping! No need to change name any more :/

Comment: @Google,  you have to vote us cause we give you the solution's.

Comment: @FrayneKonok — They don't have a high enough rep to vote.

Comment: I did't notice, Sorry @Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a change event handler and update the name based on checked property

```js
function change(ele) {
  ele.name = ele.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1" onchange="change(this)">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1" onchange="change(this)">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1" onchange="change(this)">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1" onchange="change(this)">
```

**EDIT :** 
Using jQuery

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  this.name = this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1">
```

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery you can do like this :

```
$(".myclass").change(function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
        $(this).attr("name", "nameY");
    }else{
        $(this).attr("name", "nameX");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for the checkbox is check or not, if check the reset the name attribute to `checked` other wise put `unchecked`

```
$(".myclass").on("change", function(){
    if($(this").prop('checked') == true){
        $(this).attr("name", "checked");
    }else{
        $(this).attr("name", "unchecked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, from what I can understand.

```
$("input.myclass").on("click",function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
     $(this).attr("name","nameY");
  }else{
     $(this).attr("name","nameX");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".myclass").click(function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked";
    $(this).attr("name",isChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="checked" value="myvalue1">
<input class="myclass" type="checkbox" name="unchecked" value="myvalue1">
```

you can easily use using jQuery.

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked";
    $(this).attr("name",isChecked);
});
```